# Req to reopen "How do low-wage workers get to work?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

Can we reopen [How do low-wage workers get to work?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/115258/how-do-low-wage-workers-get-to-work)

This is extremely relevant to people trying to get a leg up in life.  I've experienced this myself, and can contribute some great ideas.

Remember folks, there is more to the working world than white collar and IT jobs.

Answer (score 4):

**I do not believe this question should be reopened as is.**

This question makes a lot of assumptions, and if you remove the assumptions, the question becomes very broad. It assumes that because the OP didn't see any cars that the workers did not drive to work. It assumes that all low-wage workers do not have reliable cars. It assumes that the answer for this particular Wendy's will be applicable to all low-wage workplaces. It assumes that people in low-wage jobs get to work differently than people in higher-paying white collar jobs (i.e. this is not about white-collar vs blue-collar - it's about transportation).

If you remove all of the assumptions, the question could be boiled down to "*How do I get to work when I don't reliably have a car available to me?*" You could also possibly add for this situation "*and my work isn't accessible by public transportation.*" That could potentially be answerable, though it is a very different question from what was asked, and I think the answers are pretty obvious and straight-forward (walk, bike, public transport, dropped off, carpool).

Comment: The answers are only obvious to those who have never been in that situation, and the ones you think are obvious are wrong.

Comment: @DonThermidor_LobsterMobster I'll concede on the point that there are no "obvious" answers. Could you clarify what you mean by "the ones you think are obvious are wrong."?

Comment: Having climbed all the way up from homelessness, and gone through this, I can say that you have to be very creative.  In one instance, I had to take a bus, but the bus stop was so far away I had to either bike to it, or get dropped off.  Now, the bus only had a rack that could hold two bicycles, so if they were full, you had to take the next bus.  Then, some days, the busses were off schedule or not running, or I missed one and had to hop back on my bike part way... sometimes I could get a ride.  Then I had to walk when I got a flat tire...  Then, there's also weather to consider....

Comment: and much much more.  It may at first seem obvious that you just do "A", but it isn't that simple, easy and there is much planning you have to do.

Comment: @DonThermidor_LobsterMobster this applies to everybody in the workforce. Not just the less fortunate.

Comment: @EdwinLambregts it's very insulting to call hard working people "less fortunate".  And no, it's not the same.  Part of my dilemma was that while I had a car, I couldn't afford gas.  I also couldn't afford a taxi or these days Uber.  These are concerns that people earning more money aren't concerned with.  These days, I can take uber if I need to drop my car off because I can afford it.

Comment: @EdwinLambregts Just curious, have you ever been poor to the point of having to walk because you couldn't afford gas?

Comment: @DonThermidor_LobsterMobster I'm not sure why you think "less fortunate" would be an insult - it specifically implies that people can be hard working and *still* not have the fortune to be well off. Please don't take these arguments as personal attacks against you, or people who may not be able to afford transportation. They are specifically critiques of the question and how it is framed. So far the only mention of financial ability by the OP is the assumption that fast-food workers cannot afford to travel by car. The question of transportation without a car should not be limited to that case.

Comment: @DavidK It is insulting to call someone busting their backside to get ahead as "less fortunate."  Don't make assumptions that I'm taking anything personally.  There is nothing unfortunate about honest work.  This is condescending compassion, and is quite insulting.  Don't think so?  Would you call someone "less fortunate" to their face?  If not, you see my point.  It's not about me taking anything personally, it's about treating people with decency and respect.

Comment: @DonThermidor_LobsterMobster Then can I ask what term you prefer that accurately conveys the situation? I had always considered "poor" to be more insulting, but maybe I am incorrect. "Low-income" indicates pay rate, but doesn't really say anything about overall wealth and ability to afford daily expenses.

Comment: @DavidK there is nothing wrong with poor.  Poor isn't an insult.  I've been poor several times.  It happens.  "Having hard times" isn't bad.  I always said I was "digging myself out of a hole" after my stroke, and it wasn't bad fortune that got me there, but a malicious act, but that's another story.  I think "less fortunate" strikes a nerve with people who are poor because it sounds like you pity the person.  Nobody likes to be pitied or thought to be pitiable.

Comment: @DavidK actually, when I went from homeless to a low-paying job, I thought myself to be quite fortunate, as it was a huge step forward.

Answer (score 3):

There's merit in this, but the question will need some heavy editing to make it answerable and on-scope.

Right now, the question seems to be specific to this one situation (this fast food outlet not *appearing* to have public transport, and an assumption made based on numbers of cars in the car park.

The question is also very broad in nature.  There must be a huge variety of methods in getting people to work - carpooling, walking, public transport (of unknown means), lifts, company supplied mini-van, etc., etc.

If a question could be tight enough and answerable enough, that would be cool.